# overpass-turbo Limit to State?

Tags: openstreetmap, overpass-api

I am trying to export all `admin_level=6` using OverpassAPI.
However I am noticing a small issue as I can't seem to only show results for 1 state.

Take NT, Australia it's quite small width wise and the map view when I query it seems to grab some results for WA, QLD as well as NT.

Is there anyway to limit to a state?

Query

```
/*
This has been generated by the overpass-turbo wizard.
The original search was:
“city”
*/
[out:json][timeout:25];
// gather results
(
  // query part for: “city”
  node["admin_level" = "6"]({{bbox}});
  way["admin_level" = "6"]({{bbox}});
  relation["admin_level" = "6"]({{bbox}});
);
// print results
out body;
>;
out skel qt;
```

End result
[image: NT and results]

When you zoom out it shows[image: zoomed out results]

Answer (score 1):

You can skip bbox and add area filter. Search all supermarkets in NT:

```
[out:json][timeout:25];
area["state_code"="NT"]["is_in:country_code"="AU"]->.boundaryarea;
(
  nwr["shop"="supermarket"](area.boundaryarea);
);
out meta;
>;
out skel qt;
```